# Website accessible from everywhere except for client's network

Tags: asp.net, networking

My client has a website that is showing some strange behavior. The site is built in ASP.Net and used to be hosted on their internal network. It's now been moved to a different server outside their network. They have other sites hosted on the same server, some built using DotNetNuke, and some classic ASP. All these sites are hosted on one application server, with a database (SQL Server 2008) on a separate server (which is on the same network as the application server). They share the application server, and the database server.

Now that this site has been moved to the outside server, they can't access it. I can, and so can others that I work with (from different IPs, across the country). But the client can't from their network. They can access the landing page subsite.clientdomain.com (no db access), but nothing else. So, for instance, there's a link to subsite.clientdomain.com/folder. When they click that link, the URL changes to subsite.com/folder, which does not work. For myself and others not at the client site, the URL does not change and opens with no problems.

I didn't write the site, and didn't even know it existed before this problem cropped up, so I know very little more than this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could it have something to do with caching of some sort?

Comment: I have seen weird behavior like this with certain AV programs most recently Computer Associates security suite. Check what AV is installed and as a test uninstall it and then have then browse thesite.

Comment: I'ts a long shot but maybe it has something to do with there internal DNS server? Could you be more clear about what exactly changed during the migration and the behaviour your client has. For example new domain or the same? And is domain.com the same as clientdomain.com or are they different? This is not really clear to me.

Comment: @MartijnB, yes, sorry. I've edited my post to clarify. I've now gotten access to a pc on the client's network, and the problem is obvious. The domain of their internal network is clientdomain. So when the try to navigate to subsite.clientdomain.com, their browser's trying to access their internal network.

Comment: It could still be the DNS server but I am not convinced. The thing is that a DNS server cannot AFAIK redirect to a different URL. So something is redirecting from http://subsite.clientdomain.com/folder to http://subsite.com/folder, which could be caused by a HTTP redirect. This can be triggered by the software/website itself or by IIS.

Comment: @MartijnB, you are correct! I had thought I'd answered my own question, giving you credit in the answer, but I'm not seeing it anywhere. If you post as an answer, I'll give you credit for the correct one.

Comment: @virtuesplea Thanks! Posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go with Martijn B's answer. There's a DNS issue on the internal network. Somewhere on of the DNS servers is a definition that maps http://companywebsite to an ip address like 192.168.1.20 or whatever.

I would open a command prompt on your PC and type

```
ping new_website_name.com
```

Take a look at the IP address that comes back. You can also do an nslookup on new_website_name.com that will give you more information. If you (person A) gets one IP address and Person B (inside the network) gets a different IP address....there is definitely a DNS issue on the internal network.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do some network tracing to determine exactly where any redirection is occurring.  Given that the problem is only manifested in certain locations, it is likely that it is a function of network configuration in that location (as previously suggested).  Without understanding exactly what redirection is occurring, it would be unwise to make configuration changes that might make the problem worse or introduce new issues.

Answer (score 0):

A DNS server cannot AFAIK redirect to a different URL. So something is redirecting from subsite.clientdomain.com/folder to subsite.com/folder, which could be caused by a HTTP redirect. This can be triggered by the software/website itself or by IIS.